# How to check who is the minter of and NFT in ERC1155

Tags: solidity, blockchain, nft, erc-1155

I am working on NFT Smart Contract using ERC-1155. So when i list the item for fixedPrice Selling , i have to provide the address of **RoyaltyRecipient** to whom the royalty would be transfered.This **RoyaltyRecipient** field have to accept the address of only of the minter , who has minted the NFT. any address other than the minter is placed inside it , it should says , you are not the minter.

This is my code

```
function listItemForFixedPrice(uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _amount , uint256 _price , uint256 _royaltyFee, address _nftAddress , address _royaltyRec)public  OnlyTokenHolders(_tokenId , _nftAddress) returns(uint256)
    {
        require(_tokenId >= 0 , "TokenId can not be negative integer");
        require(_amount > 0 , "amount of nfts can not be zero");
        require(_price > 0.0001 ether  , "Price should be greater than 10 ether");
        require(_nftAddress != address(0), "NFT address cannot be 0x0000000000000000000000");
        require(_royaltyFee <= 2000 && _royaltyFee >= 150 , "Royalties fee can not be greater than 20% ");


        uint256 newItemId = Fixedprices.length;
        Fixedprices.push(FixedPrice(false,true,msg.sender,address(0),_nftAddress, _royaltyRec,_price,0,newItemId,_tokenId,_royaltyFee,_amount));
        IERC1155(_nftAddress).safeTransferFrom(msg.sender,address(this), _tokenId, _amount, "0x00");    

        emit OfferSale(newItemId);
        return newItemId;   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a mapping, everytime a mint happens store the minter of token Id in `nftArtist` -

```
mapping(uint => address) nftArtist;
```

In your `listItemForFixedPrice()` function, add below check -

```
function listItemForFixedPrice(uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _amount , uint256 _price , uint256 _royaltyFee, address _nftAddress , address _royaltyRec)public  OnlyTokenHolders(_tokenId , _nftAddress) returns(uint256)
{
    ...
    require(_royaltyRec == nftArtist[_tokenId], "Royalty receiver is not valid");
    ...
}
```

Comment: what if i want to call this require check from another contract

Comment: @UmarRaza you will need to create a public function in the contract where you have `nftArtist`. That function will give access to other contracts to read state variables of the primary contract.